# XSLT: Unable to apply UTF-16 LE BOM encoding to output file

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using Oxygen XML Editor 25.0, Saxon-PE 11.4.
I need to convert a dictionary to ABBYY DSL format, and it requires the file to be in UTF-16 LE BOM encoding. For some reason, the output file is in UTF-16 BOM format (without LE, little endian). How can I fix this?

The XML file is in UTF-8 encoding.

Here's the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:character-map name="escape-square-brackets">
    <xsl:output-character character="[" string="\["/>
    <xsl:output-character character="]" string="\]"/>
  </xsl:character-map>
  
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-16le" byte-order-mark="no" use-character-maps="escape-square-brackets"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:result-document href="/Users/xinatanil/Desktop/compiling stuff/abbyy_udahin_kg_ru.dsl" method="text">
      <xsl:text>#NAME "Кыргызско-русский словарь"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>#INDEX_LANGUAGE "Russian"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>#CONTENTS_LANGUAGE "Russian"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      
      <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="card">
          <xsl:value-of select="k"/>
          <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:for-each select="body/blockquote">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </root>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here's a small chunk of the XML I'm trying to transform

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <card>
      <k>а</k>
      <body>
         <blockquote>а I</blockquote>
         <blockquote>1. возглас удивления;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>2. вопрос с оттенком удивления или неудовольствия.</blockquote>
         <blockquote>а II</blockquote>
         <blockquote>см. ал II;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>мейли, не болсо, а болсун всё равно, будь, что будет;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>а түгүл</blockquote>
         <blockquote>1) не тот; не он;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>2) не только тот;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>а береги вон тот;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>а болду, бу болду, Эшкаранын он төөсү өлдү погов. то было, (да) это было, десять верблюдов Эшкары пало (что ни говори, а это факт).</blockquote>
         <blockquote>а III</blockquote>
         <blockquote>(неправ. вместо аа)</blockquote>
         <blockquote>см. ал II;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>а көрө муну сүйлөйлүчү вместо того (лучше) поговорим об этом;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>а эмне дедиңер? вы что ему сказали?</blockquote>
         <blockquote>бирок а Темирдин көзү жетти но Темир понял это;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>адам баласы аа эмне дебес! что (только) человек не скажет об этом!</blockquote>
         <blockquote>а IV</blockquote>
         <blockquote>р.</blockquote>
         <blockquote>союз а;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>а сен эмне үчүн кетпей отурасың? а ты почему сидишь и не уходишь?</blockquote>
         <blockquote>ах сен болсоң... а что касается тебя...; а ты...;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>а эмичи? ну, а теперь?</blockquote>
         <blockquote>а эми болсо... а вот теперь... аа см. ал II.</blockquote>
      </body>
   </card>
   <card>
      <k>аалам</k>
      <body>
         <blockquote>ар.</blockquote>
         <blockquote>мир, вселенная;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>ааламды басып шоораты фольк. слава о нём разнеслась по всему миру;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>ааламга белгилүү всемирно известный;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>он сегиз миң аалам фольк. вселенная (земля со всем населяющим её);</blockquote>
         <blockquote>он сегиз миң аалам - көк өгүздүн жонунда стих. вселенная (держится) на хребте сивого быка (по старому народному представлению);</blockquote>
         <blockquote>он сегиз миң ааламды камырдай тепсеп баскаңдай фольк. (у богатыря такой вид) будто всю вселенную может месить, как тесто;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>бул бала ааламга татыйт этот паренёк мировой;</blockquote>
         <blockquote>ааламдан ашкан см. аш- II 2.</blockquote>
      </body>
   </card>
   <card>
      <k>ааламдык</k>
      <body>
         <blockquote>несметный (букв. то, что есть во всём мире);</blockquote>
         <blockquote>ааламдык дилде, сансыз мүлк фольк. несметное количество золота, бесчисленные богатства.</blockquote>
      </body>
   </card>
</root>
```

Comment: *"The XML file is in UTF-8 encoding."* How did you determine that?

Comment: I opened the file in Notepad++ and looked at the encoding in the bottom right corner

Comment: I don't think that's a conclusive test. Was the content readable?

Comment: I am sorry, I thought you said the result was in UTF-8. I meant how are you determining the encoding of the result?

Comment: Is the detection of UTF-16 BOM as the result format also done by Notepad++? Or how do you determine that? I have run a simple stylesheet with `<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-16LE"/>` through Saxon HE 11.4 from the command line and also through oXygen 25 and Saxon PE 11.4 and the result files when opened in Windows Notepad show `UTF-16 LE` as the encoding.

Comment: Oh, I determine the result encoding the same way: by opening Notepad++ and looking and the file's encoding. There's also ABBYY DSL's compiler that throws an error if the encoding is wrong, so I know for sure that I've got the wrong encoding. By the way, if I take the result file and convert it to UTF-16 LE BOM in Notepad++, then DSL compiler gives me no errors.

Comment: Is it possible that result's file encoding is wrong because I use a Mac?

Comment: But Notepad++ is a Window program, no? As for the problem, consider to post a minimal XML and minimal stylesheet allowing us to reproduce the problem, preferably with Saxon 11 from the command line. If it only occurs with oXygen, perhaps ask their support, they are very knowledgeable and helpful. Have you tried to put the encoding also on the `xsl:result-document`?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the sample XML. And yes, unfortunately, ABBYY DSL compiler is only available on Windows and all I have is my Macbook ((. So I'm running Windows via Parallels, but I use Oxygen via macOS. I also tried adding `encoding="utf-16le" byte-order-mark="no"` to `<xsl:result-document>` but nothing changed ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. I'll try to figure out how to use Saxon via command line and I'll come back with more details.

Comment: I have tried your samples on Windows but both Notepad and Notepad++ identify the result encoding as UTF-16 LE or UTF-16 Little Endian. Let's see whether someone else is going to try on a Mac. I think both Michaels being active here are mainly Mac users.

Comment: I ran a minimized version of OP's code on Saxon 10 using the command line in macOS. The result is definitely UTF-16 Little-Endian. I don't think you can trust what a text editor says, it's merely a guess. However, if I tell the editor to use another encoding, the result becomes unreadable gibberish. I did not bother to check the existence of BOM.

Comment: BTW, OP's code says `byte-order-mark="no"` but the required format is UTF-16 LE BOM??

Comment: @michael.hor257k you're right, `byte-order-mark` is `no`. I experimented with the parameter and forgot to change it before posting. But what's interesting, it actually doesn't matter whether I set it to "yes" or "no", Notepad++ stil shows it as BOM

Comment: May need help from Oxygen support here. You haven't tagged the question Oxygen so I don't know if they're listening. Saxon will output the file in the requested encoding if given half a chance, but Oxygen settings may override this.

Comment: I installed SaxonJ-HE 11.4 via Homebrew, ran the XMLT via Terminal and result WAS the same. I almost started crying but after relaunching some stuff it WORKED! And what's more interesting now it works even via Oxygen. I don't know how it worked or what happened but I'm glad it worked. Plus, Saxon via CLI will allow to automate some stuff which is great. Thank you all, guys!